# Wiring for Logic Level Converter to 1.8V SPI Flash with a 3.3V programmer

Tags: spi, programming, flash

I have a 3.3V SPI flash programmer that I would like to use to flash a 1.8V SPI flash chip.
I have read that I could use a logic level converter to do this but I can't find wiring diagrams.

There is a good article here "[How do I write to SPI flash memory?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51229/how-do-i-write-to-spi-flash-memory)" on how to flash SPI but I can't seem to find any good article on how to wire a Logic Level Converter like "https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009" to convert 3.3V to 1.8V to flash a 1.8V SPI chip with a 3.3V programmer.

Comment: Not even the hookup guide linked from that page?

Comment: The hookup guide talks about 5V to 3.3V conversion so I was not sure if I need to add another resistor or a DC converter to bring the 3.3V down to 1.8V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my understanding of the logic level converter was wrong.
I had thought it could also convert voltage but that is not correct.
I need to supply 2 different voltages. A 3.3V on one side and a 1.8V on the other side.

Anyway, I found a link that contained the wiring I needed.
Here is a pic from the link.
http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150517/eqkfw8e9.png

[image]