# How to make an easy oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, speakers, telephone, ringing, oscillation

I want to make a very simple oscillator that produces the sound of telephone ringing (I want to make a ringer).

I will not connect it to a telephone so the quality of the sound is not important. I will connect it to a 8-ohm speaker, just for learning. That's why I wanted the circuit to be easy.

I looked at the circuit of my telephone. I didn't understand it because it has many capacitors and resistors, and it has these transistors:

S8550 D 148

S8050 D 113

2N 5551 148

2N 5401 148

S9014 D 113

Comment: Trying to replicate existing telephone is pointless. These days the easiest way is to get an MCU development board and make it to play sound with its DAC.

Comment: If you Google "electronic telephone ringer circuits", and then click on Images, you will find schematics to dozens and dozens of telephone ringer circuits (plus a few others).  Some are quite simple.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125447/playing-sounds-on-an-avr-mcu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest oscillator is bang-bang one that hits both power rails.
(search for inverter oscillator.)
Making something ring like a bell is much harder.
Bells are anharmonic.

Comment: Commonly known as a "relaxation oscillator". It would be good practice to supplement your somewhat short answer with actual examples.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to buy a super-cheap voice recorder in the toy section of the drug store and use it to record the sound of a telephone ringer. There isn't any standard "ringer sound" to mimic, so a thousand people may tell you how to make it sound "like a telephone" and they'd all be different but they'd all also be correct.

But... if you want to build something from scratch that **may** be mistaken for a telephone ringer if heard in the dark... you might try building first a simple oscillator to get a single tone. Next, add a second oscillator running at a much lower frequency, the output of which modulates the first oscillator's frequency. Unless I'm mistaken, you can accomplish this with only about two transistors and a handful of passive components.