# Sound Chips for attiny

Tags: sound, attiny

Is there some kind of chip ( that doesnt use an SD Card ) so i can play prerecorded sounds using my ATtiny?

I'm talking about the kinds of things in toys like Zoomer and furby etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main one I've used is made by ISD. [Here](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/interface-voice-record-and-playback/2556441?WT.srch=1&WT.medium=cpc&WT.mc_id=IQ67697021-VQ2-g-VQ6-38156204306-VQ15-1t1-VQ16-c) is the digikey page for all their offerings.

[image]

Another sound/speech recording/playback chip (BU6929FV-E2) from ROHM.

Answer (score 0):

Buy one of those happy birthday singing cards then switch the contacts with a ATiny port and transistor.  (Some of these cards come with a short recordable function so you can add you own sounds.)

Most of these have the chip covered.  But here is a module from Amazon that seems to have the chip exposed:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B006HL1KAU/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_2/192-9549683-4919744?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_r=10JSRBYZ6HM12W7E6PPJ&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_p=1944687562&pf_rd_i=B001U33PC6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006HL1KAU)

Several others are available thru Amazon and others

Comment: A nice little idea,  could get a few to do different sounds i suppose

Comment: Here's one of the actual chips:  http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/221200425215?item=221200425215&lgeo=1&vectorid=229466&rmvSB=true           Actually seems cheaper to buy the whole module.  Even SparkFun has assemblies:  https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10653?gclid=CN_Z67KBk8MCFcXm7AodHlMAFA

Answer (score 0):

Well 'sound' usually refers to samples of audio data. If you can generate that data fast enough on your attiny, a *digital to analog converter (dac)* is what you're looking for. Most probably though your attiny will have a hard time storing enough data for uncompressed sound snippets. I recommend looking into uLaw decoder chips. uLaw is a compression method for speech that was widely used in telecommunication equipment (e.g. answering machines) in the 90s, so hardware should be cheap. Generally, the attiny would be my least favorite microcontroller for this. Other controllers don' come at much higher cost and bring integrated dacs (in shape of high speed dacs) and have much much more space.

Also, you will need an analog low pass at the output of whatever digital circuitry you use to generate an audio signal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need any external chip to generate the sound. But you'll likely need some external chip to store the sound data unless you're generating really simple beep-beep music. You can generate the sound from any digital pin of the ATtiny. You just need some memory to store the music.

A simple medoly can be done by using a timer to switch a pin high and low. Then make an array of data to store the timer frequencies and lengths (amounts of cycles) per note.

Even better connection is to switch two pins in differential; one is low when the other is high and vice versa and then connect the speaker in between. When there's no sound, keep both low so there's no power used in the speaker.

Sampled music can be generated using PWM, but you need a lot of memory to store the samples. You'll have to run the PWM at a rather high frequency; ideally you should run several PWM cycles per sample. And instead of PWM, you can use error dithering, which is actually quite close to the sigma-delta technique used by "real" DACs. But PWM is a good option especially because the ATtiny has PWM generator included on-chip.

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/125453/11606

Comment: @Ignacio, nice. On a similar note, I once did a USB sound card by using PWM output of an AT91.